Geodesics on a gravitational wave
$$
\newcommand{\dot}[1]{\overset{.}{#1}}
\newcommand{\ddot}[1]{\overset{..}{#1}}
$$
Consider the following metric, which describes a linearized plane gravitational wave:
$$
g_{\mu\nu} = \eta_{\mu\nu} + A_{\mu\nu}\cos(k_\alpha x^\alpha)
$$
where $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric, and $A_{\mu\nu}$ satisfies $A_{\mu\nu}k^\mu = A_{\mu\nu}u^\mu = A^\mu_\mu = 0$ where $k^\mu\partial_mu = \omega(\partial_t+\partial_z)$ and $u^\mu\partial_mu = \partial_t$. Indices are still raised and lowered with the Minkowski metric. From this we can deduce that $A_{\mu\nu}$ (written as a matrix) looks like:
$$
A_{\mu\nu} \equiv 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & A_+ & A_\times & 0\\
0 & A_\times & -A_+ & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where the components of $A_{\mu\nu}$ are taken to be on the order of $\varepsilon$, with $\varepsilon$ being "small" in the sense that the linearized approximation to GR holds. Now we introduce the null coordinates $u = t - z$ and $v = t + z$, so that we have $\bar{k}^\mu\partial_mu = \omega\partial_u$ and $\bar{u^\mu}\partial_\mu = \frac{1}{2}(\partial_u+ \partial_v)$. The double use of the symbol $u$ is somewhat unfortunate, but one of them will always carry an index, so no confusion should arise. We also immediately see that the components of $A_{\mu\nu}$ do not change, since the same components vanish in either coordinate system, and the nonvanishing ones are unaffected by the transformation. We see that $\bar{k}_\alpha\bar{x}^\alpha = \omega u$, and $-dt^2 + dz^2 = -(dt + dz)(dt-dz) = -dudv$, so that the line element becomes:
$$
\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}d\bar{x}^\mu d\bar{x}^\nu = -dudv + (1+A_+\cos(\omega u))dx^2 + (1-A_+\cos(\omega u))dy^2 + 2A_\times\cos(\omega u)dxdy
$$
Introducing a parameter $s$ and taking the derivative of the coordinates with respect to this parameter, we get the Lagrangian:
$$
L = \bar{g}_{\mu\nu}\frac{d\bar{x}^\mu}{ds}\frac{d\bar{x}^\nu}{ds} = \dot{u}\dot{v} + (1+A_+\cos(\omega u))\dot{x}^2 + (1-A_+\cos(\omega u))\dot{y}^2 + 2A_\times\cos(\omega u)\dot{x}\dot{y}
$$
From which we can derive the geodesic equations through the Euler-Lagrange equations. We begin with the coordinate $v$:
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial v} = 0 = \frac{d}{ds}\frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{v}} = -\ddot{u}
$$
From this we can deduce that $u$ is either constant, or linear in $s$.
For $u$ we get the following equation:
$$
-\ddot{v} = \omega\sin(\omega u)\left[A_+(\dot{y}^2-\dot{x}^2)-2A_\times\dot{x}\dot{y}\right]
$$
For $x$, things start to get weird: Assuming that $u$ is not constant, we get:
$$
(1+A_+\cos(\omega u))\ddot{x} - A_+\omega\sin(\omega u)\dot{u}\dot{x} + A_\times\cos(\omega u)\ddot{y} - A_\times\omega\sin(\omega u)\dot{u}\dot{y} = 0
$$
And similarly for $y$:
$$
(1-A_+\cos(\omega u))\ddot{y} - A_+\omega\sin(\omega u)\dot{u}\dot{y} + A_\times\cos(\omega u)\ddot{x} - A_\times\omega\sin(\omega u)\dot{u}\dot{x} = 0
$$
These last two equations confuse me, as they look like two geodesic equations at once. Trying to eliminate $\ddot{x}$ (or $\ddot{y}$, respectively) and inserting into the other just leads to a terribly long expression that I will not even bother typing out here, and which does not feel like it goes anywhere. The exercise then asks for the solution of these equations, neglecting terms of order $\varepsilon^2$ and higher, which confuses me even further - No such terms appear in any of my equations in the first place. How would I get such terms? Should I just bite the bullet and try to work my way through the horrible expression obtained through eliminating $\ddot{x}$ or $\ddot{y}$? Or did I make a mistake somewhere in my derivations so far?

If the question is asking for a solution of order $\epsilon$, my bet is that there are many higher order terms that you are free to drop from that gross expression that you feel goes nowhere.

Sadly, that is not the case

@paulina: my other suggestion would be to work in a coordinate system where $A$ is diagonal.  Maybe that will help with the cross terms, and you will have $det A$ stuff in the denominator, where your linearization condition will help.

I was trying to avoid further coordinate transformations, but that does sound like a fruitful idea. Better than what I have right now, at least.

Oh my god, I just realized you were right all along - in my expression, I am dividing by something of order $1+\varepsilon$ instead of order $\varepsilon$, meaning I can indeed discard most of the expression. Thank you so much!

@paulina glad I could help! :)
